# Destroy event or callback of an object in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know javascript does not have destroy method, but my object needs to know when it ceases to exist.

```
class MyObject
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.interval = setInterval(this.checker, 5000);
    }

    checker()
    {
        // Stuff
    }

    beforeDestroy()
    {
        clearInterval( this.interval );
    }
}
```

I would like to clear a timeout and an interval before it's being destroyed. I'm not finding it, I'm assuming it is not possible but I would like to be sure. Any node.js version, experimental or using custom module is ok.

Comment: A solution totally depends on how `MyObject` is used.

Answer (score 1):

Cause and effect relationship is mixed up here. It's not possible to determine the moment of time when `MyObject` instance is destroyed. Usually objects that aren't referenced anymore can be garbage-collected.

`beforeDestroy` is usually implemented by frameworks as a hook, e.g. AngularJS `$onDestroy`, Angular `ngOnDestoy`, React `componentWillUnmount`. A place that is responsible for `MyObject` instantiation should also be responsible for calling `beforeDestroy` when it's known that an instance is not needed anymore. Then an instance can be garbage-collected.